# convert JSON Type to Byte array format in java

Tags: java, json, byte

I have a problem when I want to sending data using byte format in UDP protocol, the problem is when I try to create a data with type json object, I can't get the byte format of my data this is my sample code:

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("name", "foo");
    obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
    obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
    obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));
    obj.put("nickname",null);

    sendData = obj.getBytes(); //this is error because not have methos getBytes();
```

i know my problem but i can't found how to convert json object to byte, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Get the bytes of the string:

```
obj.toString().getBytes(theCharset);
```

Comment: `getBytes` should be passed an encoding. Otherwise ... no fun when it isn't the assumed "default encoding".

Comment: Check my answer bellow to see how to avoid unnecessary conversion to a `String` and additional *encoding* based on the provided *charset*: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39412196/3114959

Comment: JSONObject and an a String both are different representations of data. What we see in notepads is String representation of JSON Data, not the actual data. For example if you see an int value 65535 in your notepad, this is actually a string of characters 6,5,5,3 and 5 (five characters = 5*2 bytes = 10 bytes in java) , rather a single int value 65535 (4 bytes in java).

Answer (score 34):

Assuming the JSONObject you mention is from [this](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html), you can get the bytes like below

```
sendData = obj.toString().getBytes("utf-8");
```

Comment: yes you right too...:) so i give some up in each answer ...:)

Comment: @Agung the link is no longer valid, can you tell what is the use if this ?

Answer (score 3):

To avoid unnecessary conversion from `String` to `byte[]` which enforces encoding based on the provided *charset*, I prefer to use `JsonWriter` directly with `ByteArrayOutputStream` for instance (`JsonValue` subtypes use `JsonWriter` with `StringWriter`):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Json.createWriter(stream).write(obj);

byte[] sendData = stream.toByteArray()

System.out.println("Bytes array: " + sendData);
System.out.println("As a string: " + stream.toString());
```

Additionally, one can even enable *pretty printing* as follows:

```
Json.createWriterFactory(
            Collections.singletonMap(JsonGenerator.PRETTY_PRINTING, true))
        .createWriter(stream)
        .write(obj);
```

The only sad thing is that it's not an *one-liner*. You'd need 3 at least (given the fact that you omit calling `JsonWriter.close()` which is unnecessary in this context).

Comment: Json.createWriter(stream).write(obj);

The above line only takes Javax.json type obj and not JSONObject (which is mentioned in the question). If you try to cast it like : Json.createWriter(stream).write((JSONObject)obj); 

It throws exception : cannot cast.

Any suggestions for JSONObject type object.

Comment: where is `Json` coming from?

Answer (score 3):

Use utility class from `ObjectMapper` of `jackson-databind` project, ie `objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(dto)` returns `byte[]`

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

ContractFilterDTO filter = new ContractFilterDTO();
    mockMvc.perform(post("/api/customer/{ico}", "44077866")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(filter)))...
```

Maven dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Oh! I missed to use objectMapper after knowing it..., I have updated my code though. thanks.