# How to convert JSONObject directly to byteArray without intermediate toString?

Tags: android, arrays, json

I have a JSONObject returned from a library. Sometimes the JSONObjects are too big and they cause an exception when applying toString to the JSONObject before applying getBytes to convert it to a byteArray. How do I convert JSONObject to ByteArray directly?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39412196/6950238) answer.

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Please suggest a library compatible with javax.json in Android. The above example is working in Java. But for android, the same library is not available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35257532/11514311 Look at this link. I think it will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Json.createWriter(byteArray).write(jsonObject);
byte[] data = stream.toByteArray()
```

Comment: What library should I implement to use Json in Android?

Comment: Here's a documentation about Jackson https://github.com/pgelinas/jackson-javax-json

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("name", "foo");
    obj.put("num", new Integer(100));
    obj.put("balance", new Double(1000.21));
    obj.put("is_vip", new Boolean(true));
    obj.put("nickname",null);
```

Your solution :

```
obj.toString().getBytes(theCharset);
```

Comment: toString method hits the exception for me. The JSONObject is too big sometimes.